# Calling NetworkingV1Api().list_namespaced_ingress(namespace=namespace) raises AttributeError

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-python-client

I'm using kubernetes python client library to list all ingresses in a namespace. I'm using the api [NetworkingV1Api()](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/NetworkingV1Api.md#list_namespaced_ingress). When i run the code, its throwing the error *"**AttributeError: 'NetworkingV1Api' object has no attribute 'list_namespaced_ingress'"***

```
from kubernetes import client, config

config.load_kube_config(config_file=os.environ.get("KUBECONFIG",'my-cluster.config'),context=os.environ.get("KUBECONTEXT"))

v1=client.NetworkingV1Api()
ingress_list=v1.list_namespaced_ingress(namespace=ns1)
print(ingress_list)
```

Can someone please help on this issue. I'm able to execute other api resources using this client.

I'have tried with ExtensionsV1beta1Api() and CoreV1Api(), but still no luck.

Comment: Are you on an older version of the kubernetes python library, perhaps?

Comment: @botje, could you please help me in checking the version, what is the command should i use to check. the python version was 3.9.16

Comment: That answer depends on the package manager you're using. If you used pip it could be as simple as `pip freeze`.

Comment: Thanks, seems earlier i just used ```pip install kubernetes``` and it installed some older version. Now, i have used ```pip install kubernetes==27.2.0```. Which solved the issue. Thanks @botje